# Is there a possibility to retrieve liquipedia page content in json?

Tags: html, json, wikipedia

I got this page - https://liquipedia.net/dota2/Players_(all) which I want to get in JSON format, is there any open liquipedia (which is actually wikipedia based site) api's I can use? Or maybe there are approaches to convert html to json?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a python API that would do what your looking for at https://github.com/c00kie17/liquipediapy#dota_get_players